# using xpath to parse images from the web

Tags: python, xpath

I'm written a bit of code in an attempt to pull photos from a website. I want it to find photos, then download them for use to tweet:

```
import urllib2
from lxml.html import fromstring
import sys
import time

url = "http://www.phillyhistory.org/PhotoArchive/Search.aspx"

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
dom = fromstring(html)

sels = dom.xpath('//*[(@id = "large_media")]')

for pic in sels[:1]:

    output = open("file01.jpg","w")
    output.write(pic.read())
    output.close()




#twapi = tweepy.API(auth)
#twapi.update_with_media(imagefilename, status=xxx)
```

I'm new at this sort of thing, so I'm not really sure why this isn't working. No file is created, and no 'sels' are being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the image search (`Search.aspx`) doesn't just return a HTML page with all the content in it, but instead delivers a **JavaScript** application that then makes several subsequent requests (see [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)) to fetch raw information about assets, and then *builds* a HTML page dynamically that contains all those search results.

You can observe this behavior by looking at the HTTP requests your browser makes when you load the page. Use the [Firebug extension](http://www.getfirebug.com) for Firefox or the builtin [Chrome developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) and open the **Network** tab. Look for requests that happen *after* the initial page load, particularly POST requests.

In this case the interesting requests are the ones to `Thumbnails.ashx`, `Details.ashx` and finally `MediaStream.ashx`. Once you identify those requests, look at what headers and **form data** your browser sends, and emulate that behavior with plain HTTP requests from Python.

The response from `Thumbnails.ashx` is actually [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), so it's *much* easier to parse than HTML.

In this example I use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module because it's much, much better and easier to use than `urllib(2)`. If you don't have it, install it with `pip install requests`.

Try this:

```
import requests
import urllib


BASE_URL = 'http://www.phillyhistory.org/PhotoArchive/'
QUERY_URL = BASE_URL + 'Thumbnails.ashx'
DETAILS_URL = BASE_URL + 'Details.ashx'


def get_media_url(asset_id):
    response = requests.post(DETAILS_URL, data={'assetId': asset_id})
    image_details = response.json()
    media_id = image_details['assets'][0]['medialist'][0]['mediaId']
    return '{}/MediaStream.ashx?mediaId={}'.format(BASE_URL, media_id)


def save_image(asset_id):
    filename = '{}.jpg'.format(asset_id)
    url = get_media_url(asset_id)

    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        response = requests.get(url)
        f.write(response.content)
    return filename


urlqs = {
    'maxx': '-8321310.550067',
    'maxy': '4912533.794965',
    'minx': '-8413034.983992',
    'miny': '4805521.955385',
    'onlyWithoutLoc': 'false',
    'sortOrderM': 'DISTANCE',
    'sortOrderP': 'DISTANCE',
    'type': 'area',
    'updateDays': '0',
    'withoutLoc': 'false',
    'withoutMedia': 'false'
}

data = {
    'start': 0,
    'limit': 12,
    'noStore': 'false',
    'request': 'Images',
    'urlqs': urllib.urlencode(urlqs)
}

response = requests.post(QUERY_URL, data=data)
result = response.json()

print '{} images found'.format(result['totalImages'])

for image in result['images']:
    asset_id = image['assetId']
    print 'Name: {}'.format(image['name'])
    print 'Asset ID: {}'.format(asset_id)

    filename = save_image(asset_id)
    print "Saved image to '{}'.\n".format(filename)
```

**Note**: I didn't check what http://www.phillyhistory.org/'s Terms of Service have to say about automated crawling. You need to check yourself and make sure you're not in violation of their ToS with whatever you're doing.